# Understanding guard clauses in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to implement a guard clause in Elixir.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
def fib(n) when n < 1, do: n
```

But when I test this, this error appears:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in ProjectEuler.fib/1
```

For the life of me I can't seem to understand the problem here.

Comment: We are going to need to see more code than this. I assume you only have that one function definition. You will want at least a second one because the one you have shown only matches if the number passed into it is less than one.

Comment: Ahh, that may be my problem then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code you've provided it looks like you have a module with only one function - the one shown here. I assume you have something like this:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def fib(n) when n < 1, do: n
end
```

so, if you run code like:

```
MyModule.fib(1)
```

This will fail. This is because your `fib/1` can't be matched as it has this guard clause `when n < 1`.

In order to make it pass, you need to add another function - less restrictive (with different guard clause, or without any):

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def fib(n) when n < 1, do: n
  def fib(n), do: fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
end
```

This will make `MyModule.fib(1)` call the proper definition.

You need to be aware - when using this technique, VM will try to match argument analysing function definitions in order they are defined in the module, so:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def fib(n), do: fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
  def fib(n) when n < 1, do: n
end
```

Will be problematic, as `fib` with `when` clause will never be matched, as the less restrictive is defined first.

Hope that helps!